# rider C# plugin: how to create a run configuration and then run it

Tags: c#, rider, rider-plugin

Using the SampleContextAction from https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-rider-plugin I'm trying to create a ContextAction that "detect" comments like this:

```
//>Filestar.exe -load=*MediaToolKit* -command="convert to webp" sample:sample.mp4
```

And the create a run configuration and then execute it?

I'm stuck on creating a run configuration and then executing it?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it's much easier and more promising to directly ask the JetBrains guys in their Slack channel when it comes to developing plugins. You can request an invitation [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/slack).

Comment: Thanks I will ask to join their Slack.